# Update profile to firestore cloud with current user with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The Error am having now it in the photo is giving my instance of future

IT  will update and upload on the fire store cloud but the aspect of photoUrl it giving instance of future

```
 Future<void> uploadPic(BuildContext context) async{
      // String fileName = basename(newProfilepic.path);
       var randomno = Random(25);
      final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =  FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('profilepics/${randomno.nextInt(5000).toString()}.jpg');
    final  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(newProfilepic);
  await   uploadTask.onComplete.then((value){
      userManagement.updateProfilePic(value.ref.getDownloadURL().toString()).then((val){
        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homesceen');

      });
     }).catchError((e){
        print(e);
      });
    }

Future updateProfilePic(picUrl) async {
    var userInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
    userInfo.photoUrl = picUrl;

  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
          .getDocuments()
          .then((docs){
              Firestore.instance
                  .document('users/${docs.documents[0].documentID}')
                  .updateData({'photoURl':picUrl}).then((val){
                    print('Updated');

                  }).catchError((e){
                    print(e);
                  });
          }).catchError((e){
            print(e);
          });
    }).catchError((e){
      print(e);
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you call `updateProfilePic` you pass in `value.ref.getDownloadURL()` which actually returns a future and not the url. You have to `await` or `then` it to get the string path.

I think if you type your function parameters you'd see a warning about mismatched types. Try

```dart
Future updateProfilePic(String picUrl) async {}
```

instead of

```dart
Future updateProfilePic(picUrl) async {}
```

If a user is only allowed one `user` entry as well, I'd get rid of

```dart
Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .getDocuments()
```

and replace it with

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).update(/* */)
```